# SQL Server with peer-to-peer replication migration from on-prem to AWS EC2 instances

Tags: sql-server-2012, migration, amazon-ec2, master-master-replication

I need to move three on-prem servers with peer-to-peer replication to AWS.
SQL Server version is 2012. The AWS SQL Server will be on EC2 instances as the SQL Server RDS doesn't support replication yet. Databases are relatively small with around 3 TB data.

I am thinking to have following steps:
On the day before the D-Day

- Prep EC2 instances for SQL.
- Install required versions and upgrade to same SP as on-prem.
- Copy full and diff backups upto that day to EC2 servers.
- Get TDE certificates.
- Restore to common point in time for all three servers.
- Establish replication between servers.

On D-Day

- Copy differential backup and logs from each server to corresponding AWS Server.
- Restore the differential and recover to same point in time by applying logs.

I might be able to get few hours of downtime but the servers are live and I need to accomplish this with minimal downtime.If someone has come across similar scenario, I would appreciate any inputs for best practices. 
Also, DMS has limitations for us so we will need to skip that option and try to go for lift-and-shift.

Comment: SQL Gurus, please advise on this process.